# What are some law related to recording video during one at work? (let's assume the manger agrees)

Tags: privacy, california

Let's say someone is doing vlog for tiktok and youtube. we can see some people taking video during the job.  People who work as cashier at a gas station take videos, people work in big company take video.

What are some laws we need to know if one decides to take videos during theirs work.
Sure, they should get permission from their manager, and coworkers who are in the video.

What about the cashier situation?  We can see some videos where the people get their faces covered up with emoji or some other pictures. At the same time, we often see people facial expression. (not sure if the cashier asked for permission already)

What if the  cashier working in a not so nice neighborhood and decided to take video with own equipment for safety issue additional the webcam in the store. (not intent to pose online)

Q. what are some rules/laws we need to consider when taking videos of others?

Comment: I doubt there are any special rules about doing it at work. The laws would almost certainly be the same laws as if you were a customer, or just passing by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends **very** much on the jurisdiction. Before you do anything like it, talk to lawyers specializing in employment law and privacy law where you live.

- People on the web are breaking the law all the time. Some do not know what they are doing, others are gambling that nobody will bother to prosecute them. When the police knocks on their door or a summons arrives in the mail, they are surprised ...
- Privacy and possibly other rights of the people in the picture may be affected. You might need something like a [model release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_release) from each and every one of them, or only from those who are significantly visible.
- Even if there is no *intent* to post these pictures, you are still processing personal data. Regulations like the [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) might affect how they can be taken. There might be a requirement to post notice about the cameras, how to contact the company privacy officer, etc.
- The employer would probably have to permit/order this if it is done on company premises.

Comment: just added california

Comment: @user95432, then you need a specialist from California. My first bullet point remains universal, however.